# How can I remove this bg white that appears only when I focus an input element? I’m using BS5.3.2 in React + Vite, also if I set a background, no work

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I want to remove this background white that appears in the floating label when I focus the input element in BS5. I’m using React + Vite, I’ve also set the background to none and searched in the community for a solution but I found nothing

[Here there’s a image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiXp4.jpg)

Comment: please include code your code so we can help